# Item click doesn't fire event when clicking on border

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a strange problem with the event, `itemclick` on Extjs and the selection model of type `checkboxmodel`.

I defined a tree panel, and in the configuration I set:

```
selType: 'checkboxmodel',
selModel: {
    mode: 'SINGLE'
},
```

After, in the controller,  attach the event to the function:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'MyTree': {
             itemclick: this.openItem
         }
    });
},
```

Everything works perfectly **except when I click inside the item, in the minimum border separating the items. In that case, the checkbox changes, but the event doesn't fire.**

I tried with the event `onmousedown` and `itemdblclick` but the result is the same. Is there any way to prevent this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-select) event instead of `click`, since your intention is to react to the selection.